# Writing a PDF file on the user local

Tags: java, pdf, web-applications, file-upload

My web application has a feature of uploading PDF files to the web that is executed the following proccess:

1. Create a folder which path is `C:/resource/pdf/`
2. Then write a PDF inside the folder

Is it possible for a web application to create a folder then write a PDF file inside it? I tried this and it is working perfectly fine, on my local. But when I deployed the app in the web ( free hosting ) there is an error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/resource/pdf/Daily News.pdf (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.neu.als.thesis.web.controllers.UploadController.writeFile(UploadController.java:129)
at com.neu.als.thesis.web.controllers.UploadController.uploadPDF(UploadController.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I know lines 129 and 71. I tested it again in my eclipse and it is working. Is there any restriction on web application when it is deployed or anything similar that preventing me to create a folder?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your permissions on the server and who's account the server is running under, you may not have permissions to write to that directory.  Typically, the safe bet for saving a file to the server locally is to create a temp directory or something inside of your apps directory structure to put the files in.  You should have permission to write to that directory as long as it's in your apps file structure.